# find out object type with its path

Tags: java, cmis

I have to find out the type (folder/file) of an object with it's directory path.

e.g. I have to find out that the object with this path is a file.

```
/home/user/test.docx
```

I found a solution that works but it isn't really a good one.

```java
try {
    final Folder parentFolder = (Folder) session.getObjectByPath(path); 
    //throws exception when path points to a file
    //do sth when it's a folder
} catch (final Exception e) {
    //do sth when it's a document/file
}
```

I can't use 'instance of' here because i can't get the object (with session.getObjectByPath) wihout knowing the type of the output.

Is there a better way to find out the object type with it's path?

Comment: hint: `instanceof`

Comment: @Martin you have to be more specific. Like, what was the output of your code? Do you mean `file` by Object?

Comment: i cant use instanceof because i can't convert the String to the object without knowing the output type (file/folder)

Comment: I added some more details

Comment: you can use isDirectory for given path string ?

Comment: @f1sh you are right it works with instanceof

Comment: u can answer the question so that i can mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of type casting this to Folder directly you can use the `instanceof` like this:

```
CmisObject cmisObject = session.getObjectByPath(path);

if (cmisObject instanceof Document) {
    Document document = (Document) cmisObject;
} else if (cmisObject instanceof Folder) {
    Folder folder = (Folder) cmisDocument;
}
```